# How can I convert such a model into a BoundaryMeshRegion

Tags: import, mesh

The obj file is [here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/Mathematica/blob/master/Bug%26%26Problem/Problem%40BoundaryMeshRegion/house_004.obj)

[image]

As you see, I cannot import such a house model into Mathematica with BoundaryMeshRegion Option.

```
Import[objFile, "BoundaryMeshRegion"]
```

So my question is How can I convert such a model imported as MeshRegion into a BoundaryMeshRegion with similar shape[we can modify some parts of the original model].
Or Cut the model into parts of BoundaryMeshRegion models.

```
meshRaw=Import[objFile,"MeshRegion"]
```

this is related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219753/how-can-i-calculate-volume-of-such-a-meshregion-object), we can see, BoundaryMeshRegion object can calculate Volume directly.

[image]

Comment: Normally one would use `RegionBoundary`, but the mesh has to have a proper boundary.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Sometimes, the mesh is really not a BoundaryMeshRegion, but we can remesh the model to make it into a BoundaryMeshRegion like doing that in 3d softwares' Remesh function, for example, remesh in Blender. So I wonder whether we can have a simple way to get a similar BoundaryMeshRegion in Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, RegionBoundary won't work if the MeshRegion is already just a 2D surface. When I had to deal with this last time, I used a remeshing tool from MATLAB through MATLink. `RepairMesh` sometimes helps, but it usually does not.